# What will happen if I install windows using custom install?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I can't boot my PC using my windows installed in my C drive since  I think the files are corrupt, so I have windows installed on a flash drive and am installing it to see if I can save some  of the files to a usb before clean installing windows on my PC. If I do custom install will it wipe the files from all drives? or will it just install a new windows entirely and wont affect them? If it is going to wipe my drives then I will probably just remove the drives from my PC and install windows on a new one then put the drives back in unless someone can also help me with that

Comment: Boot from a bootable USB and recover your files to another USB drive before trying to do a fresh install of Windows on your regular drive.

Comment: “will it wipe the files from all drives?” - Yes

Comment: Well, not "all" drives....

Comment: @Moab - Should have read that question more carefully.  It will wipe the Windows partition at least.

Comment: but not  "all drives"

Answer (score 0):

It will ask you to select a partition to install to. That partition will be wiped, others won't.

Nevertheless, **make backups first**. You're one misclick away from losing your files. You almost did already and now instead of being prepared, you have to come up with a rescue plan. Be prepared next time, because you may be less lucky and there will be nothing to rescue.

Comment: Good advice -- but make a **complete disk image**, not just a backup of Windows System files.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's always a good idea, but in this case I'd say OP should focus on their personal files. The system is unbootable anyway. Image will be handy in case they miss something important when backing up, but in general restoring from a regular folder will be more convenient than from an image,